# How to handle font hinting (pixel alignment) for images rendered using PhantomJS?

Tags: html, css, fonts, phantomjs, python-imaging-library

We are converting a rendering project which was based on PIL to use PhantomJS instead. This makes layout management a breeze, by relying on HTML rules.

Sadly, we cannot find a way to enforce font hinting for images rendered by Phantom JS. PIL was automatically making sure that the horizontal and vertical lines in fonts were aligned on the pixel grid (making for optimally sharp edges). Prototyping with PhantomJS, we realize that it does not try to enforce such a constraint, at least not by default.

Is it possible to achieve this pixel hinting behaviour with PhantomJS ?

Comment: alternative question: PhantomJS is a real browser, unlike PIL, so why would PIL messing with the alignment be a *good* thing when you're testing client side interaction? You want that "real browser behaviour" that PhantomJS (and other headless browsers) offer, so you can do proper testing, I assume.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have a hard time putting your comment in the context of this question. We are converting an offline rendering project, not testing client side interaction: nothing related to distributing web pages to *real users* ;)

Comment: that was exactly my point: you're using a headless browser, which is great at being a headless browser. If you're not using it for doing server-side testing of client-side behaviour, why are you using a headless browser? You may be using a spanner to hammer in a nail here, without realising the spanner's not a hammer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because it makes layout management very easy in our case (our layout fitting nicely the CSS box model).

Comment: Basically once you hit real browsers, all bets around font alignment to pixel grids (excepting fonts that come with their own embedded bitmap tables) are off. Sizing is now purely done based on how well your CSS controls your positioning. You'll also run into the issue that fonts are nowhere near as crisply rendered on browsers as in something like PIL (typography on the web, despite having become really popular in recent years, is still years behind desktop/programmatic precision)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans From my one day experience of comparing PIL with Phantom/Chrome, I would tend to agree a lot with your comment, especially the last point you are making !